# Find Value Hash Similar to LIKE sql (Ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How to search for a value similar to SQL `LIKE` in a hash?

Example:

```
[ {:x=>"Hello"},{:x=>"Hello 1"]]
```

I want search all values contain 'he'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
haystack = [{:x=>"Hello"}, {:x=>"Hello 1"}, {:x=>"Goodbye"}]

haystack.find_all do |entry|
  entry[:x] =~ /he/i # /i makes it case insensitive
end

#=> [{:x=>"Hello"}, {:x=>"Hello 1"}]
```

Comment: Thanks friend, in this case how replace 'he' by a variable example search = 'he' ?? thanks

Comment: replace he by  /#{search_term}/i where search_term is my variable

Comment: exactly. Note that @ForgetTheNorm's answer does the same thing as for `Array`, although having a slightly different implementation in MRI, `find_all` and `select` do the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

With an `include` ?

```
a.select{|e| e[:x].include?('he')}
```

Or with a regex `match` ?

```
a.select{|e| e[:x] =~ /he/}
```